# Create a random background image for gui

Tags: image, matlab, random, background

I am trying to create a function that will choose a picture for the background image for my gui at random.  I tried doing this by creating random integers from 1 to 6 (i have 6 different background images to choose from) and then writing if statements where if the integer is equal to a certain value, then a certain image will be called.  it works the first time I run the gui, and then every time after that I just get a grey background and no image.

```
    % creates the 'background' axes
ha = axes('units','normalized','position',[0 0 1 1]);
% Move the background axes to the bottom
uistack(ha,'bottom');

% Load in a random background image and display it using the correct colors
bg = randi(6);  % random integer
handles.p = 0;  % background image variable

% pick a background based on random integer
if bg == 1
    handles.p = imread('dark.jpg');
elseif bg == 2
    handles.p = imread('powerup.PNG');
elseif bg == 2
    handles.p = imread('what.jpg');
elseif bg == 2
    handles.p = imread('earth.PNG');
elseif bg == 2
    handles.p = imread('namek.PNG');
elseif bg == 2
    handles.p = imread('namekexplode.PNG');
end

hi = imagesc(handles.p);
colormap gray;
% Turn the handlevisibility off and make the axes invisible
set(ha,'handlevisibility','off', 'visible','off');

clearvars handles.p
```

This is my attempt.  Please help

Answer (score 1):

You've written `bg == 2` repeatedly instead of 3, 4, 5 ...

Comment: You're right.  I feel very stupid...  Thank you so much though!  It works now